# Identificar scroll no final da div

Tags: javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      alert(“bottom!”);
   }
});
```

Estou tentando colocando esse código em uma `div`, já consegui mudar o `window` só não sei oque colocar no lugar do `document` pra funcionar.

Comment: e o que extamente esse código deve fazer?

Comment: Não consegui entender o seu problema. Talvez se colocar um trecho do HTML e explicar melhor o que quer fazer...

Comment: identificar quando o scroll estiver no final da div / window

Comment: esse código esta pronto para identificar quando o scroll estiver no final da window

Comment: mas eu quero colocar ele pra identificar na div e nao na window inteira, entendeu agora?

Comment: Continua sem fazer sentido. Seja mais claro e detalhado. Edite a pergunta e colocando um [mcve] que possamos reproduzir e entender o que deseja fazer.

Comment: Você tem que levar em conta que só você tem as informações sobre o seu software. Nós não sabemos nada a respeito dele então você tem que nos guiar até o problema para que possamos o resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez uma opção seja trabalhar com a API `Observer` diretamente no JS

O que nos permitirá:

- Identifique quando um elemento observado, neste caso, o "div" atinge uma certa proporção de visibilidade através da propriedade "threshold"
- Podemos indicar em um intervalo de 0 a 1
- Talvez aqui a opção seja: quando o elemento estiver em "90%", é claro visível, seria "0,9" para indicar alguma ação em consequência

Exemplo:

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container")

const checker = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    console.log("div's edge")
  }
}, {
  threshold: .9
})

checker.observe(container)
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut aspernatur, excepturi voluptates beatae numquam voluptatum delectus at nemo ab ea, inventore possimus quidem deserunt blanditiis ipsum obcaecati eius hic minima!</span>
  <span>Perspiciatis explicabo optio ipsam doloribus labore quidem, vero assumenda ex sequi voluptate excepturi. Animi accusantium asperiores quod. Laudantium, praesentium? Ea, rerum. Sint dolorem harum temporibus blanditiis quidem, suscipit, excepturi optio.</span>
  <span>Quia sapiente consequuntur doloribus dignissimos, sit odio accusamus ex illum placeat maiores officiis atque voluptatum, dolores distinctio eos voluptatem dolore itaque. Sapiente deserunt magnam, accusamus itaque autem quas temporibus non!</span>
  <span>Iste fuga sequi aliquam illo reprehenderit. Asperiores alias itaque, beatae nemo ipsa odio illo. Illum non voluptates saepe, ab unde itaque harum, animi dolorem, ipsa libero aliquid magnam distinctio obcaecati.</span>
  <span>Autem totam atque tempora sed consectetur animi, alias neque. Deleniti iste et, incidunt expedita blanditiis, necessitatibus nostrum illo officiis eius corrupti deserunt nemo, possimus quaerat ratione vel sint eum. Doloribus.</span>
  <span>Ipsam hic, vero deleniti. Repellat pariatur provident autem illo quas doloribus impedit aliquid obcaecati, modi, at molestiae cumque. Ipsum quos corporis eaque sequi suscipit, inventore ex sunt consequuntur incidunt rem.</span>
  <span>Amet debitis quae omnis, iure, distinctio labore ut neque reiciendis voluptate architecto. Eveniet reprehenderit quos magni, fugiat magnam similique maxime molestias tempora cum, esse libero neque, totam, deserunt earum reiciendis.</span>
  <span>Tempora, aspernatur, esse? Omnis fuga blanditiis, porro explicabo dicta qui nam magni, quidem doloremque? Minus quasi enim eum perferendis hic, voluptatibus sapiente facilis, fugiat voluptas. Libero, maxime commodi totam eum.</span>
  <span>Omnis, cum. Numquam deleniti laudantium voluptatibus quo cupiditate sed, saepe omnis pariatur eum rerum, iusto corporis cum, culpa ipsa provident ducimus possimus illum ea doloremque quasi quod non. Maiores, fugit.</span>
  <span>Qui magni consectetur modi laudantium esse quas impedit aut nesciunt. Ad ea nobis nisi qui explicabo quaerat possimus ipsa, atque odit quam molestiae voluptatum fugiat. Eos sed expedita ipsam ratione.</span>
  <span>Omnis numquam ex sint quas fugiat quos adipisci! Laborum quam explicabo nostrum, maxime veniam qui sapiente, reprehenderit officiis quod, odit, repudiandae tempora optio deserunt culpa a vel recusandae vitae distinctio.</span>
  <span>Expedita inventore nobis hic, iusto non illum nam animi temporibus aperiam quis voluptatem distinctio dolorum, optio fugiat odit sapiente quaerat velit doloremque eaque laudantium alias totam eum, quia ipsam quam?</span>
  <span>Expedita neque ipsa facilis fugit numquam voluptas obcaecati culpa dicta incidunt esse delectus officiis beatae minus animi atque pariatur nihil voluptates rem quasi tenetur magni non saepe, repellendus. Minima, id.</span>
  <span>Aspernatur perspiciatis debitis eos veritatis, repudiandae modi non dignissimos optio ipsam sed repellat, quam adipisci expedita similique odio dolore eum. Eaque assumenda, ex quae accusantium nemo, voluptatibus veritatis veniam vitae.</span>
  <span>Facilis in cumque minima architecto, a fugit quibusdam quia nisi, autem commodi cum temporibus. Repudiandae laudantium, dolorum perspiciatis soluta culpa aperiam recusandae. Eum animi doloremque modi reiciendis earum! Eos, facilis.</span>
</p>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

- [aqui você pode ler mais sobre a referida API:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: esse código é interessante, mas está vendo "quando o scroll chega na div".... consegue editar e colocar o paragrafo dentro de uma div, e testar quando o scroll dessa div chegou a 90%? ai estaria bem de acordo com a pergunta

Comment: @RicardoPontual 
com certeza sim, apenas me dê uma chance e mais tarde farei isso porque já começo o meu dia de trabalho.